# Unable to import RetinaDataset from core.datasets, it throws ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to import a dataset, retinadataset, from core.datasets, but it says there is no module named core with the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

I have tried installing python-core. I have anaconda3 installed with no other environments(base only). I am using a windows10 machine.
The error is as follows:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10608/1953950398.py in <module>
     11 import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
     12 import random<br>
---> 13 from core.datasets import RetinaDataset
     14 from core.datasets.data_util import preprocess_image, preprocess_for_train
     15 from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

Please help

Comment: You need to install `tensorflow_datasets` and use `from tensorflow_datasets.core.datasets.data_util import preprocess_image, preprocess_for_train`

Comment: Actually there are several other packages that are being imported from **core**

Comment: What's with all these `<br>` at the end of your code lines?

Comment: @desertnaut, corrected that, can you help with the solution, please?

Comment: So which `core` module do you want to import? Is it https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/core this one? Then just put a `tensorflow_datasets.` in front of every `core` import